Grpc client (net.devh:grpc-client-spring-boot-starter) set retry policy
I am using net.devh:grpc-client-spring-boot-starter lib, with @GrpcClient annotation to get to client grpc stub based on application config (application.yml), I would like to override the retry policy.
The java grpc examples (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/retrying/RetryingHelloWorldClient.java) refer to updating the ManagedChannelBuilder.
Any example of how to do this with @GrpcClient?
Would I create a GrpcChannelConfigurer bean that sets the relevant retry properties on the ChannelBuilder?
I verified it worked by either:

Spring grpcChannelConfigurer config bean
Manually creating  ManagedChannelBuilder and newBlockingStub(channel)


If it worked by setting retry config via the GrpcChannelConfigurer, what is your question then?
